# Rails form select population

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, form-for

I was trying to create a simple form which listed a users name in a select box.

```
<%= f.select :user, @users.all {|a| [a.name]} %>
```

`@users` is just `User.all`

Whats odd is I've spent the best part of 20 minutes reading through some confusing rails documentation trying to find a simple answer.

I cannot figure out how to populate the dropdown with the user names.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use the `collection` option: `f.select :user, collection: @users.all.map { |a| [a.id, a.name] }` ... Perhaps with `id` and `name` reversed (I can never remember)... I'm not even sure if the `map` is required, Rails may auto-magically figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few ways to do that but Rails provides the `collection_select` helper that makes it easy:

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_id, @users, :id, :name %>
```

This will use `user_id` as the select name, `@users` as the collection and finally will fetch `id` and `name` out of every user and use it as the option's value and text.