# Rails 4 dropdown menu pulling from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I am trying to implement a dropdown menu to display all the names I have in my database. I tried unsuccessfully the following code:

```
<%= form_for @airline, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :name, [@airlines.names] %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def index
    @airlines = Airline.all
    @airline = Airline.new
end
```

I assume the solution is quite straight forward but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Are you getting an error or some unexpected results? It's hard to help without knowing of the issue. Also, if I had to guess your issue is probably with what you're using as your data: `@airlines.names`. How are you defining `@airlines` in your controller?

Comment: @mmichael No error. I get a dropdown with one option 'Airline'.  I added the controller above.

Comment: @user2573222 Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550192/rails-form-select-population/27550347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do

```
<%= f.select(:name, @airlines.collect { |airline| [airline.name,airline.id] }, {:include_blank => 'Choose 1'},:class=>"class_name") %>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Can you explain, or point me to documentation to understand exactly what's going here?

Comment: You can check here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select its a `rails` helper which will convert to `select` html tag internally.